# Selecting a position from a lists using Python

Tags: python

I want to create a program that selects a team from a lists and display the players name and postion.

Something like this:

```
Enter the team: A
Enter the position number: 1
```

Then it should print something like this:

```
At postion 1 is John
```

This is what I got so far:

```
def display_team(TeamNum, Team):
   print "Team" + TeamNum + ": "
   for player in Team:
       print player

#main
#Lists used to define the teams
TeamA = ["John", "Peter", "Philip", "Ben"]
TeamB = ["Bill", "Tommy", "Pete", "Manny"]

display_team('A', 'TeamA')
display_team('B', 'TeamB')


team = raw_input("Enter the team: ")
position = int(raw_input("Enter the position:"))

raw_input("\nPress enter to continue")
```

Comment: So, what's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to the end of your code :

```
if  'A' is team:
    print 'TEAM A\n', 'At Position ', position , TeamA[position - 1]
if  'B' is team:
    print 'TEAM B\n', 'At Position ', position , TeamB[position - 1]
```

Comment: I did insert the code but it doesnt work. It still doesnt display the player position with the player name.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your teams more easily accessible by putting them in a dict:

```
teams = { "A": ["John", "Peter", "Philip", "Ben"],
          "B": ["Bill", "Tommy", "Pete", "Manny"] }
```

Then:

```
print "At position", position, "is", teams[team][position - 1]
```

should print the name in question. You're going to have to change the team printing in `display_team()` too.

Comment: I found this question on my Python book on the lists chapter.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `Team` lists in a dictionary firstly:

```
d = {'A':TeamA, 'B':TeamB}
```

Then, after you have your inputs, you can do:

```
print "At position {0} is {1]".format(position, d[team][position - 1])
```

Remember that indexing starts at `0`, so `John` is at index 0.